How should I modify my code so that mouse-drawn lines remain on the canvas of the window during window scrolling
I am using win32 api to make a paint program, when I try to solve that using mouse to draw lines,remain the lines in the canvas, it can't work well.
This is the Win Process Function:
LRESULT MainWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int canvasWidth = 1200;              //初始的画布大小, initialize canvas width
    static int canvasHeight = 700;              //初始的画布大小, initialize canvas height
    static int workWidth = canvasWidth + 60;    //设定的工作区大小, set work area width
    static int workHeight = canvasHeight + 60;  //设定的工作区大小, set work area height
    static std::vector<Scroll*> scrolls;        //滚动条容器, Scroll container
    static RECT clientRC;                       //窗口客户区矩形, window client rectangle
    static HDC hMemDC;                          //内存设备上下文, memory device context
    static HBITMAP hMemBM;                      //内存位图, memory bitmap
    static POINT ptPreviouse;                   //鼠标上一次位置, previous mouse position
    static POINT ptCurrent;                     //鼠标当前位置, current mouse position
    static bool bDraw = false;                  //是否开始绘制, whether to start drawing
    static HDC hDC;                             //绘图设备上下文, drawing device context
    static RECT canvasRect;                     //画布区域, canvas area
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT mouseEvent;                 //鼠标追踪事件, mouse track event
    static int CanvasLTop_X = 0;                //画布的左上x坐标, canvas left top x
    static int CanvasLTop_Y = 0;                //画布的左上y坐标, canvas left top y
    static int OldCanvasLTop_X = 0;             //上一个画布的左上x坐标, previous canvas left top x
    static int OldCanvasLTop_Y = 0;             //上一个画布的左上y坐标, previous canvas left top y
    static int VscrollPos = 0;                  //垂直滚动条位置, vertical scroll bar position
    static int HscrollPos = 0;                  //水平滚动条位置, horizontal scroll bar position

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        // 分析菜单选择:
        //analysis menu selection
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, MainWindow::About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
            // TODO: 在此处添加按钮事件处理代码...
            //TODO: add button event handling code here...

            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // TODO: 在此处添加控件创建代码...
        //TODO: add control creation code here...
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRC);
        hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

        //创建垂直滚动条
        //create vertical scroll bar
        Scroll* VerticalScroll = new Scroll(hWnd, SB_VERT, 0, workHeight, clientRC.bottom);
        scrolls.push_back(VerticalScroll);

        //创建水平滚动条
        //create horizontal scroll bar
        Scroll* HorizontalScroll = new Scroll(hWnd, SB_HORZ, 0, workWidth, clientRC.right);
        scrolls.push_back(HorizontalScroll);

        //创建内存设备上下文
        //create memory device context
        hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        hMemBM= CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hMemBM);
        PatBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, clientRC.right, clientRC.bottom, WHITENESS);

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

    }

    break;

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        DRAWITEMSTRUCT* ptrDIS = (DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)lParam; // 转换为DRAWITEMSTRUCT结构, convert to DRAWITEMSTRUCT structure

        // TODO: 在此处添加绘制控件代码...
        //TODO: add control drawing code here...
    }
    break;

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        // TODO: 在此处添加大小变化事件处理代码...
        //TODO: add size change event handling code here...

        hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

        //将内容保存至临时位图
        //copy content to temporary bitmap
        HDC tempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        HBITMAP tempBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, clientRC.right, clientRC.bottom);
        SelectObject(tempDC, tempBM);
        BitBlt(tempDC, 0, 0, clientRC.right, clientRC.bottom, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRC);

        //更新滚动条信息
        //update scroll bar information
        for (Scroll* scroll : scrolls)
        {
            if (scroll->widgeType == SB_VERT)
            {
                SCROLLINFO newVSI = scroll->GetScrollStruct();
                newVSI.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
                newVSI.fMask = SIF_ALL;
                newVSI.nMax = workHeight;
                newVSI.nPage = clientRC.bottom;
                scroll->UpdateScrollInfo(hWnd, newVSI);
            }

            if (scroll->widgeType == SB_HORZ)
            {
                SCROLLINFO newHSI = scroll->GetScrollStruct();
                newHSI.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
                newHSI.fMask = SIF_ALL;
                newHSI.nMax = workWidth;
                newHSI.nPage = clientRC.right;
                scroll->UpdateScrollInfo(hWnd, newHSI);
            }

        }

        //计算画布的新位置
        //calculate new canvas position
        if (clientRC.right - 45 < canvasWidth) CanvasLTop_X = 30;
        else CanvasLTop_X = (clientRC.right - canvasWidth) / 2;

        if (clientRC.bottom - 45 < canvasHeight) CanvasLTop_Y = 30;
        else CanvasLTop_Y = (clientRC.bottom - canvasHeight) / 2;

        //将临时位图内容复制到内存设备上下文
        //copy temporary bitmap content to memory device context
        hMemDC= CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        hMemBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, clientRC.right, clientRC.bottom);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hMemBM);
        PatBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, clientRC.right, clientRC.bottom, WHITENESS);
        BitBlt(hMemDC, CanvasLTop_X, CanvasLTop_Y, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, tempDC, OldCanvasLTop_X, OldCanvasLTop_Y, SRCCOPY);

        //更新画布坐标
        //update canvas coordinates
        OldCanvasLTop_X = CanvasLTop_X;
        OldCanvasLTop_Y = CanvasLTop_Y;

        DeleteObject(tempBM);
        DeleteDC(tempDC);

    }
    break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // TODO: 在此处添加使用 hdc 的任何绘图代码...
        //TODO: add any drawing code using hdc here...

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRC);

        //获取滚动条位置
        //get scroll bar position
        for (Scroll* scroll : scrolls)
        {
            if (scroll->widgeType == SB_VERT)
            {
                VscrollPos = scroll->GetScrollPos(hWnd);
            }
            if (scroll->widgeType == SB_HORZ)
            {
                HscrollPos = scroll->GetScrollPos(hWnd);
            }
        }

        //跟新画布区域
        //update canvas area
        canvasRect = { CanvasLTop_X - HscrollPos, CanvasLTop_Y - VscrollPos , CanvasLTop_X + canvasWidth - HscrollPos, CanvasLTop_Y + canvasHeight - VscrollPos };
        
        //将内存设备上下文内容复制到窗口设备上下文
        //copy memory device context content to drawing device context
        BitBlt(hDC, canvasRect.left, canvasRect.top, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, hMemDC, canvasRect.left, canvasRect.top, SRCCOPY);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

    }
    break;

    case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
        // TODO: 在此处添加垂直滚动条事件处理代码...
        //TODO: add vertical scroll bar event handling code here...

        SCROLLINFO verticalSI;

        for (Scroll* scroll : scrolls)
        {
            if (scroll->widgeType == SB_VERT)
            {
                verticalSI = scroll->GetScrollStruct();
                int newPos = scroll->GetScrollPos(hWnd);
                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                case SB_LINEUP:
                    newPos -= 10;
                    break;
                case SB_LINEDOWN:
                    newPos += 10;
                    break;
                case SB_PAGEUP:
                    newPos -= verticalSI.nPage;
                    break;
                case SB_PAGEDOWN:
                    newPos += verticalSI.nPage;
                    break;
                case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                    newPos = verticalSI.nTrackPos;
                    break;
                }

                if (newPos < 0) newPos = 0;
                if (newPos > verticalSI.nMax - verticalSI.nPage) newPos = verticalSI.nMax - verticalSI.nPage;

                ScrollWindowEx(hWnd, 0, scroll->GetScrollPos(hWnd) - newPos, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE);
                scroll->UpdateScrollInfo(hWnd, newPos);
                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_HSCROLL:
    {
        // TODO: 在此处添加水平滚动条事件处理代码...
        //TODO: add horizontal scroll bar event handling code here...

        for (Scroll* scroll : scrolls)
        {
            if (scroll->widgeType == SB_HORZ)
            {
                SCROLLINFO horizontalSI = scroll->GetScrollStruct();
                int newPos = scroll->GetScrollPos(hWnd);
                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                case SB_LINEUP:
                    newPos -= 10;
                    break;
                case SB_LINEDOWN:
                    newPos += 10;
                    break;
                case SB_PAGEUP:
                    newPos -= horizontalSI.nPage;
                    break;
                case SB_PAGEDOWN:
                    newPos += horizontalSI.nPage;
                    break;
                case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                    newPos = horizontalSI.nTrackPos;
                    break;
                }

                if (newPos < 0) newPos = 0;
                if (newPos > horizontalSI.nMax - horizontalSI.nPage) newPos = horizontalSI.nMax - horizontalSI.nPage;

                ScrollWindowEx(hWnd, scroll->GetScrollPos(hWnd) - newPos, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE);
                scroll->UpdateScrollInfo(hWnd, newPos);
                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
        bDraw = true;
        ptPreviouse.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        ptPreviouse.y = HIWORD(lParam);
    }
    break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (bDraw)
        {
            MoveToEx(hMemDC, ptPreviouse.x, ptPreviouse.y, nullptr);
            LineTo(hMemDC, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
            BitBlt(hDC, canvasRect.left, canvasRect.top, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, hMemDC, canvasRect.left, canvasRect.top,  SRCCOPY);
            ptPreviouse.x = LOWORD(lParam);
            ptPreviouse.y = HIWORD(lParam);

            mouseEvent.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            mouseEvent.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
            mouseEvent.hwndTrack = hWnd;
            TrackMouseEvent(&mouseEvent);
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        bDraw = false;
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    }
    break;
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        bDraw = false;
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    }
    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        //释放scrolls容器中的对象
        //release objects in scrolls container
        for (Scroll* scroll : scrolls)
        {
            delete scroll;
        }
        scrolls.clear();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    break;


    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

Effect:
First draw

Scroll down the window:

Scroll back:

Second draw


On a side note: your WM_SIZE is leaking the old hMemDC and hMemBM objects when the window is resized. It needs to free them. Also, CreateCompatibleDC() creates the HDC with a 1x1 bitmap initially, which you are also leaking after replacing it with SelectObject().  You need to either free that initial bitmap, or save it and restore it before freeing hMemDC.

Do not draw directly on your window outside of a WM_PAINT message handler.  Anything you draw will be erased the next time the window is repainted.
You have a couple of options:

Have your mouse handler save the coordinates in a list somewhere, and then have a WM_PAINT handler (re)draw all of the lines currently in the list.

Create an in-memory bitmap with the same size as your window, and have the mouse handler draw lines on that bitmap as needed. Whenever the bitmap changes, call InvalidateRect() to trigger a window repaint. Then have a WM_PAINT handler draw the current bitmap as-is onto the window.


You appear to be attempting the 2nd approach, except that your WM_MOUSEMOVE handler is drawing the bitmap onto the window immediately instead of waiting for the next WM_PAINT message to arrive.
Try something more like this:
RESULT MainWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...

    switch (message)
    {
    ...

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        ...
        BitBlt(hDC, ..., hMemDC, ...);
        ...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;

    ...

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        bDraw = true;
        ptPreviouse.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        ptPreviouse.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    }
    break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (bDraw)
        {
            MoveToEx(hMemDC, ptPreviouse.x, ptPreviouse.y, nullptr);
            LineTo(hMemDC, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
            ptPreviouse.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            ptPreviouse.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, TRUE);
            ...
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        bDraw = false;
    }
    break;

    ...
    }

    return 0;
}


Thank you very much for your answer. I have a question: If the size of the window changes, the size of HBITMAP "hMemBM" need to update.
So:
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
    ....
    hMemBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, clientRC.right, clientRC.bottom);
    .....
    }

the content of hMemBM will be cleared. So, Whether should I create a temp bitmap as my code writes to temporarily save the contains of the un-updated hMemBM?

Yes, you need to create a new memory bitmap and memory dc and copy the old pixels to the new bitmap. You are doing that, but you also have to free the old ones, which you are not doing.

I see. Thank you again
